# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.flywaydb.core.api.MigrationType when using baselineOnMigrate

Tags: java, spring-boot, flyway

I'm trying to use Flyway to create another migration table in a existant schema. The main idea is that every microservice will create their own tables if they are specific to it.

The problem is that, since the schema is not empty, flyway prompts that I need to run `baseline()` or add baselineOnMigrate to my spring application config to run it. When I do it I get the following error when the app starts up:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flywayInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/flyway/FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/flywaydb/core/api/MigrationType
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1154) ~[spring-context-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:908) ~[spring-context-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147) ~[spring-boot-2.7.4.jar:2.7.4]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734) ~[spring-boot-2.7.4.jar:2.7.4]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408) ~[spring-boot-2.7.4.jar:2.7.4]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308) ~[spring-boot-2.7.4.jar:2.7.4]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) ~[spring-boot-2.7.4.jar:2.7.4]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295) ~[spring-boot-2.7.4.jar:2.7.4]
        at app.doov.search.api.pagesapi.PagesApiApplication.main(PagesApiApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.7.4.jar:2.7.4]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/flywaydb/core/api/MigrationType
        at org.flywaydb.database.mysql.MySQLDatabase.getRawCreateScript(MySQLDatabase.java:145) ~[flyway-mysql-8.5.13.jar:na]
        at org.flywaydb.core.internal.database.base.Database.getCreateScript(Database.java:318) ~[flyway-core-9.8.1.jar:na]
        at org.flywaydb.core.internal.schemahistory.JdbcTableSchemaHistory$1$1.call(JdbcTableSchemaHistory.java:117) ~[flyway-core-9.8.1.jar:na]
        at org.flywaydb.core.internal.jdbc.TransactionalExecutionTemplate.execute(TransactionalExecutionTemplate.java:55) ~[flyway-core-9.8.1.jar:na]
        at org.flywaydb.core.internal.schemahistory.JdbcTableSchemaHistory$1.call(JdbcTableSchemaHistory.java:113) ~[flyway-core-9.8.1.jar:na]
        at org.flywaydb.database.mysql.MySQLNamedLockTemplate.execute(MySQLNamedLockTemplate.java:58) ~[flyway-mysql-8.5.13.jar:na]
        at org.flywaydb.database.mysql.MySQLConnection.lock(MySQLConnection.java:152) ~[flyway-mysql-8.5.13.jar:na]
        at org.flywaydb.core.internal.schemahistory.JdbcTableSchemaHistory.create(JdbcTableSchemaHistory.java:103) ~[flyway-core-9.8.1.jar:na]
        at org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbBaseline.baseline(DbBaseline.java:88) ~[flyway-core-9.8.1.jar:na]
        at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.doBaseline(Flyway.java:368) ~[flyway-core-9.8.1.jar:na]
        at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.lambda$migrate$0(Flyway.java:161) ~[flyway-core-9.8.1.jar:na]
        at org.flywaydb.core.FlywayExecutor.execute(FlywayExecutor.java:204) ~[flyway-core-9.8.1.jar:na]
        at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.migrate(Flyway.java:128) ~[flyway-core-9.8.1.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayMigrationInitializer.afterPropertiesSet(FlywayMigrationInitializer.java:66) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.4.jar:2.7.4]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
        ... 23 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.flywaydb.core.api.MigrationType
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520) ~[na:na]
        ... 39 common frames omitted
```

These are my relevant db dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
    <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
    <version>9.8.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
    <artifactId>flyway-mysql</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

And this is the application.yml flyway part:

```
flyway:
  enabled: true
  url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dev?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true
  user: root
  password: dev
  defaultSchema: dev
  baselineOnMigrate: true
  table: "flyway_schema_history_search_api"
  locations: classpath:/db/migration
```

Anyone knows whats going on? I would appreciate some guidance. Thanks.

I've tried to remove `baselineOnMigrate: true` from my app config but then flyway prompts:

```
Caused by: org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: Found non-empty schema(s) `dev` but no schema history table. Use baseline() or set baselineOnMigrate to true to initialize the schema history table.
```

As expected.

I'm trying to have different migration history tables, per ms accessing the db.

Answer (score 0):

After reading this github issue: https://github.com/flyway/flyway/issues/3413 I downgraded flyway to the 8.0.0 version and now it works fine.